# Asynchronous Mail Plugin implementation in grails

Tags: email, grails, asynchronous

I am trying to implement **Asynchronous Mail Plugin** in Grails project. I have followed all steps of [This Tutorial](http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail)

In this I am not able to inject **asyncMailService** object into me controller class. Import to

`import grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService`

not recognized.

Here is my code for sending mail :

`AsynchronousMailService asyncMailService
        asyncMailService.sendMail {
            to 'xxx@gmail.com'
            subject 'Test';
            html '<body><u>Test</u></body>';
        }`

In above code `AsynchronousMailService` is not recognized.

I am able to send mail using below code :

`sendMail {
            to 'xxx@gmail.com'
            subject 'Test';
            html '<body><u>Test</u></body>';
        }`

But this is not sending mail asynchronously. I want to send mail asynchronously.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because you aren't injecting the service correctly. Your controller should look something like this:

```
package com.example
import grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService

class MyController {

  AsynchronousMailService asyncMailService // this injects the service

  def someFancyMethod() {
    ...
    asyncMailService.sendMail {
      to 'xxx@gmail.com'
      subject 'Test';
      html '<body><u>Test</u></body>';
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Notice that you are injecting the service outside the method.